# JavaScript loop in jQuery autocomplete, change source array

Tags: javascript, json

I am terrible at JavaScript but trying to get better. I have a simple autocomplete form that uses a JSON call. The codes looks like this:

```
        $('#TreasureMakers').ajaxChosen({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/treasures/find.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            jsonTermKey: 'q',
            placeholder_text_single: 'pick stuff'
                }, function (data) {
                    var results = [];
                    $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                        results.push({ value: val.value, text: val.text });
                    });
            return results;
                });
```

And find.json returns results like this:

```
[{
 value: "17854",
 text: "1.00"
 },
 {
 value: "13521",
 text: "1.01"
 },
 ...
}]
```

I would like to try and rewrite the loop to return the same results, but with JSON source data that looks like this:

```
results: [{
    Treasure: {
        accnum: "1.00",
        id: "17854"
    }
},
{
    Treasure: {
        accnum: "1.01",
        id: "13521"
}
},
...
]}
```

I imagine this shouldn't be too hard, but I am not even sure where to start. I tried doing something like this

```
results.push({ value: val.results[0].Treasure.id text: val.results[0].Treasure.accnum  });
```

But the Console returns an error and it does not work. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.map` for this:

```
results.push(val.results.map(function(t){
    return { value: t.Treasure.id, text: t.Treasure.accnum };
});
```

See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for more information about `Array.prototype.map`.

Essentially the `map` function does a transformation: transforming the elements of an array from one thing to another.  We're just taking the elements (objects with a property `Treasure`), and converting them to objects with properties `value` and `text`.  It's very instructive to set a breakpoint in your code and try various `map` calls in the console to get a feel for how it works.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help. My only change was `return results[0];`